# Search for a dynamic value in a column and update value if required

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kinda of a newbie in the excel VBA world and I guess my problem is simple but I cannot get around it.

In `sheet 1`, I have the number of a client that is `Won`, meaning a `client`.

In `sheet 2`, I got the number of the client and if he is a `client` (won), `prospect` or `lost`.

I want to update `Sheet 2` so when I run the macro, the fact that Person1, Person2,... becoming a client is shown in the sheet and updated.

My idea was to select the client number in `Sheet 1`, go to the client number in `Sheet 2`. If the value next to it is different than Client then Put client in it.

I'm putting screenshots of a test with the specific rows and columns.

[image]

[image]

I'm open to suggestions. thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) I think you may have misunderstood how stackoverflow operates. You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you see the 'Developer' tab.

If not, go to File > Options. In the Excel Options window that appears, look for and click 'Customize Ribbon'. In the 'Choose commands from' drop down list, look for 'Developer'. Click on it and click 'Add>>' on the right. This adds 'Developer' to the right section names 'Main Tabs'. Click to check the 'Developer' in there and click OK.

Now go to Developer > Visual Basic.

This opens Visual Basic Editor. Go to Insert > Module. This will add Module1 under Modules in Project Explorer.

Paste the following code in that module and run pressing F5 by placing cursor anywhere inside the sub routine.

If you want to run this on the click of a button. Insert a shape on the sheet. Right click on shape and click 'Assign Macro'. In the window that opens, double click the name of the subroutine you want. In this case it is AssigningClientStatus.

```
Sub AssigningClientStatus()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, fndRng As Range


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")


    For Each rng In ws1.Range("O2", ws1.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
        Set fndRng = ws2.Range("B1", ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=rng.Value)
        
        If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
        
            fndRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Client"
            
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Avin. I was already using visual basics but I had problem with the code, yours did everything perfect. Thank you a lot !!!